# vs shell installation has failed with exit code 1638

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have received the following error while installing MSSQL 2017 on Windows 2012 R2.

```
vs shell installation has failed with exit code 1638
```

[image]

Comment: For me it was McAfee that was causing the issue. Disabling the virus scanner solved the problem for me

Comment: Happens on Windows 10 v. 1809 fresh install, if you install Visual Studio before Sql 2017 Developer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must install SQL Server first before installing Visual Studio 2017.

If you have already installed Visual Studio 2017, do not worry, just follow the steps below:

Uninstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) and (x64)

[image]

Then install SQL Server.

Do not forget to select "**Database Engine Services**"

[image]

Change "**Startup Type**" of SQL Server Browser from "**Disabled**" to "**Automatic**"

[image]

The installation will be done without any problems:

[image]

Then reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable [(x86)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746571) and [(x64)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572)

Answer (score 4):

This Error means 
1-Another version of this program is already installed
2-Visual Studio 2017 Is In Installing Level And Not Complete
3-Visual Studio 2017 installed (Not For All)
If You Have Other Version . Remove Or Update The SSMS.
If Your Visual Studio In Installing Level. Wait To Complete And Then Try To Setup
Else
 To fix the issue, use the following workarounds:

Repair the x64 version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable from Add or remove programs by using following steps:

Open Add or remove programs.
Find and select Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64). Click the Change button.
Click the Repair button.
If you encounter this issue when installing TFS, you can start VC_redist.x64.exe from the TFS installation files, and then select repair.
Hope This Help You To Fix
[Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4092997/vc-2015-redistributable-install-error-1638-when-newer-version-present)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Visual Studio 2017 installed in your computer? If so, try uninstalling it, then install SQL Server, and reinstall Visual Studio. I had the same problem today when installing MSSQL 2017, and solved it like that.

I read in some sites you can also try only uninstalling Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (86x) and (64x), but I didn't try this solution, so I'm not sure if it works. It's still worth a shot though, as it's easier than uninstalling the whole Visual Studio.

Comment: Uninstalling Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 as you mentioned and installing the C++ 2015 did the trick in my case.